# Difference between Fallback and prompt message (Dialogflow)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bots, dialogflow-es

Does anyone know the difference between a `fallback message` and a `prompt message` in `Dialogflow`?

I've read several docs and I am not able to see the differences properly and also because prompt messages are not working in an agent I'm developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fallback message

A [fallback message](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents) (fallback intent) is just simply a fallback expression that is used when Dialogflow can't link an intent to the question being asked by the user. A simple example might be:

> Book a bus ticket for me.

If an Intent is not listed that can match this phrase, a fallback message might be:

> I'm sorry, I don't know what to do with that

The following image is taken from:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#referencing_parameter_values_in_fallback_intents

[image]

#### Prompt messages

On the otherhand a prompt message is just simply dialog that is initiated when you need to collect more information from the user for a detected intent. Consider the same question again:

> Book a bus ticket for me.

If this matches an intent, a prompt (follow up question) might be

> Ok would you like to book for today or another day?

See the following image taken from the Dialogflow website:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/dialogs

[image]

Comment: So if I have an intent in which a user must enter just a number (@sys.number), I can't use the prompt message to say something like "Sorry, you have not entered a number, please try it again" in the case when a user types for example a string: "Testing" because the intent will not be detected. Is that correct?

Comment: If you have a prompt where you're asking a user to enter a number and they enter "Testing" you should use a fallback to say "Sorry, you have not entered a number, please try it again". See this link: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/follow-up-intent-expressions

Comment: Got it. Thanks for you help

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help!